Handling '#' Special Character in SAP BODS
I am working on an SAP BODS solution where my target is a tab delimited file.
The problem I am facing is in source for a particular column the value is coming as "Toshiba#e-STUDIO501". Now for these rows the value after "#' is getting shifted to next column.
Can someone tell how can I handle this?
